# How would I remove non-duplicates from a CSV file in Python?

Tags: python

I have a CSV file with the following format:

```
User1, User2
1,2
1,3
2,1
```

I am trying to remove the non-duplicated reverse values, so in this instance I would like to remove `1,3` as it doesn't have a reverse duplicate of `3,1`

I currently have this script which removes the duplicate values:

```
import csv

reader=csv.reader(open('facebook-friendships.csv', 'r'), delimiter=',')
writer=csv.writer(open('facebook-friendships-write.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',')

entries = set()

for row in reader:
   key = (row[0], row[1])
   key = tuple(key)
   if key in entries and key[::-1] in entries:
       writer.writerow(row)
       entries.add(key)
```

How would I edit this script to remove the non-duplicated reverse values? So that I am only left with

```
1,2
2,1
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to maintain the order of lines in the csv?

Comment: @abhiarora no, the order can be random

Comment: You have already the logic to select the duplicate values, if you add a `not` you reverse the logic and keep the non duplicated ones. `if not (key in entries and key[::-1] in entries):`

Comment: @alec_djinn Ah thanks so much! I was putting ```key not in``` rather than the way you have specified. This work's great!

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Remove non-duplicates from a `CSV` file?

1. First aggregate the `data` using the `sum(...)` of the `data` as `key`
2. Loop the aggregated `data` and write only if **more than one** aggregated in a specific `key`.

```
reader = [('1','2'), ('1','3'), ('2','1')]
data_counter = {}

for row in reader:
    key = sum([int(v) for v in row])
    data_counter.setdefault(key, []).append(row)

print(data_counter)

for value in data_counter.values():
    if len(value) == 1:
        print('non duplicate {}'.format(value))
    else:
        # writer.writerows(value)
        print('writer.writerows({})'.format(value))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> {3: [('1', '2'), ('2', '1')], 4: [('1', '3')]}
>
> writer.writerows([('1', '2'), ('2', '1')])
> non duplicate [('1', '3')]
> ```

Comment: How would I make this work with my current code? I am reading the data in from a CSV file, it is not hard coded

Comment: @AF_web My example `data` is equal to your `row`, changing to `for item in reader:` should do it. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

```
reader = [
    [1, 2],
    [1, 3],
    [2, 1],
    [4, 5],
    [5, 4],
    ]

entries_dict = {}

for row in reader:
    sorted_row = tuple(sorted(row))
    if sorted_row not in entries_dict:
        entries_dict[sorted_row] = [row]
    else:
        entries_dict[sorted_row] += [row]

for duplic_rows in [rows_item for rows_item in entries_dict.values() if len(rows_item) > 1]:
    for row in duplic_rows:
        print(row) # writer.writerow(row)
```

Or you can use groupby:

```
from itertools import groupby

reader = [
    [1, 2],
    [1, 3],
    [2, 1],
    [4, 5],
    [5, 4],
    ]

def get_key_from_row(row):
    return tuple(sorted(row))

sorted_rows = sorted(reader, key=get_key_from_row)
grouped_rows = [list(it) for k, it in groupby(sorted_rows, get_key_from_row)]  

for duplic_rows in [rows for rows in grouped_rows if len(rows) > 1]:
    for row in duplic_rows:
        print(row) # writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply loop through each row and check whether a particular row's reverse exists or not. If yes, then it is written in the same sequence as present in the original csv file. Advantage being the original sequence is maintained.

```
import csv

reader=csv.reader(open('facebook-friendships.csv', 'r'), delimiter=',')
writer=csv.writer(open('facebook-friendships-write.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',')

allRows = []
for row in reader:
    allRows.append(row)
for i in range(len(allRows)):
    for j in range(len(allRows)):
        #Checking whether or not the index is same.
        #If index is same then there's no need to check the value at that particular index.
        if i!=j: 
            if allRows[i]==allRows[j] or allRows[i][::-1]==allRows[j]:
                writer.writerow(tuple(allRows[i]))
```